# Not able to run the testng.xml file of webdriver from the command promt

Tags: xml, command-line, testng

I am able to execute my testng.xml file successfully from eclipse.
But I need  to execute my testng.xml file from command prompt. But below command is not working,getting error as, "Could not find or load main class testng-6.8.5.jar;". Any help is more appreciated.

java -cp C:\Users\tempkanag\Downloads\selenium-java-2.43.1\selenium-2.43.1\libs testng-6.8.5.jar;  org.testng.TestNG  C:\SPC Framework\SPCOutFiles\testng.xml

Regards,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that's because some command line parameters you passed contains spaces. In this case, you need to wrap every atomic string within double-quotes so that they are recognized as one unit :

> java -cp "C:\Users\tempkanag\Downloads\selenium-java-2.43.1\selenium-2.43.1\libs testng-6.8.5.jar; org.testng.TestNG" "C:\SPC Framework\SPCOutFiles\testng.xml"